# "Snatch a nap"/"take a nap"/"have a nap"

Tags: differences

Can we say "to snatch a nap"? If it's possible then Is there any difference between "snatch a nap", "take a nap" and "have a nap"?

Comment: Lol.  "Snatch."  You might steer clear of using *snatch* and the idea of going to bed in the same sentence.  I'm just sayin'.  Besides, we *take a nap,* *catch some shuteye*, *saw some logs,* *catch a few Zs,* *get forty winks,* and even *study Jacob's dream,* but we don't *snatch a nap,* not that people wouldn't catch your drift, though.

Comment: It's moderately [idiomatic](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=snatch+a+nap%2C+snatch+some+sleep&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csnatch%20a%20nap%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csnatch%20some%20sleep%3B%2Cc0) to say "snatch some sleep".  "Snatch a nap" somewhat less so.

Comment: "Catch a nap" is fine. "Snatch a nap" is not so fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can we say "to snatch a nap"?

As far as I know this would be a new idiom.  But, well this kinda thing is where new idioms come from so I can't really say no.

[ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=snatch+a+nap%2C+take+a+nap%2C+have+a+nap&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csnatch%20a%20nap%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctake%20a%20nap%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chave%20a%20nap%3B%2Cc0) has this since before the 1860's. It's just had very minor usage compared to the others.

> **snatch**
>
> verb
>
> 1. quickly seize (something) in a rude or eager way.
>      "she snatched a cookie from the plate"
>      synonyms:   grab, seize, take hold of, get one's hands on, take, pluck;
>
> noun
>
> 1. an act of snatching or quickly seizing something.
>      "a quick snatch of breath"
> 2. WEIGHTLIFTING
>      the rapid raising of a weight from the floor to above the head in one movement.
>
> [google.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=snatch&oq=snatch&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#q=define+snatch)

Snatch a nap sounds catchy.  It would seem to mean that not only was the sleep short (a nap) it happened quickly (you didn't take hours to fall asleep).

> Is there any difference between "snatch a nap", "take a nap" and "have a nap"?

If my interpretation of it is correct then yes there is a slight difference.  Until it catches on though I wouldn't count on everyone seeing it exactly the same.

Answer (score 3):

You have Herman Melville on your side.  From [*White jacket; or, The world in a man-of-war*](https://books.google.com/books?id=DgYGAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA129&dq=%22snatch%20a%20nap%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwinurvr1rHKAhWMPiYKHT0FD2QQ6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=%22snatch%20a%20nap%22&f=false) (1850):

> But most of this side, also, is occupied by the carpenters,
>   sail-makers, barbers, and coopers. In short, so few are the corners
>   where you can **snatch a nap** during daytime in a frigate....

We have the equivalent term "grab a nap," which the Ngram viewer can trace back to 1924.  Both of these locutions imply that the rest time is stolen from other activities on the fly.  Taking or having a nap may be done at your leisure and at any time.