# "Have a nap" or "Take a nap"?

Tags: american-english, british-english, dialects

I'd like to know what's the difference between:
"We decided to **have** a nap" and "We decided to **take** a nap".

Is it a BrE / AmE thing?

Comment: There's not really any difference. Like _a shit_ or _a break_, one can either _have_ or _take_ a nap. But you _get_ or _have_ a good night's sleep, you _give_ or _have_ a look at something. It's all idiomatic, and every idiom is unique. Sorry about that.

Comment: @John Lawler I'm not sure you *give* a look at something. Did you mean *take* a look? (It's all give and take!)

Comment: Either one with _look_. Small verbs like _give, take, come, go, have,_ etc. get used in a **lot** of idioms and constructions. _Push/Give a push; Look/Give/Take a look; Try/Have a try._

Comment: **Possible Duplicate**: “Snatch a nap”/“take a nap”/“have a nap”
 https://english.stackexchange.com/q/300450/14666

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, there is no difference. Depending on context, **to have** can have various meanings, one of which is "take".

He has a car - has = owns; possesses, etc.

He has a headache - has = is experiencing; is suffering from

We had a shower - had  = took

We had a shower - we used to own a shower

Comment: @Illiana that much was already established before you even asked this question. You were long past the point of wondering if "have a nap" is a thing that exists. You started by acknowledging that it does, then other people have confirmed that that is indeed the case, and now you're not so sure anymore. That's an interesting plot twist.

Answer (score 0):

"We decided to **take** a nap" sounds more correct to me.